# What data load on my DB should I expect if I get more users?

Tags: sql, sql-server

currently as a single user, it takes the 260ms for a certain query to run from start to finish.

what will happen if I have 1000 queries sent at the same time? should I expect the same query to take ~4 minutes? (260ms*1000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to make predictions without any knowledge of the situation.  There will be a number of factors which affect this time:

- Resources available to the server (if it is able to hold data in memory, things run quicker than if disk is being accessed)
- What is involved in the query (e.g. a repeated query will usually execute quicker the second time around, assuming the underlying data has not changed)
- What other bottlenecks are in the system (e.g. if the webserver and database server are on the same system, the two processes will be fighting for available resource under heavy load)

The only way to properly answer this question is to perform load testing on your application.

Comment: I understand that my situation is not as simple as I put it. I will have to do further research. Thank you!